# Please can someone tell me what this says in engish?

Tags: translation

[image: Picture is turned sorry!]

Just wanted to know what this symbol was. My friend got the tattoo 15 years ago and she has no idea what it is.

Comment: Translation questions are off-topic unless prior research effort has been shown.

Comment: Note also that the image is rather low quality, which is also rather undesirable.

Comment: Why would anyone get a tattoo without bothering to find out what it says?

Comment: Ling Xing's answer is correct. Though anyway the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

It's this: 恋, it is also sideways

It means Love, admiration or desire

Comment: Well spotted...